# Search Generic List<T> for Id property

Tags: c#

I have a Generic List which can contain different class objects. Al these classes have the same base class which has a Id property.

I would like to do a search for the Id in the List and extract the first occourence, something like this

```
T result = myGenericList.Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault()
```

However I cannot get to the properties, I only get as far as: i => i.

EDIT:
I'm asked to provide the code for the myGenericList. Here it goes:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Initialize()
{
  List<T> allCalls = new List<T>();

  var phoneCalls = new PhoneCall[]
  {
    new PhoneCall{Id = 1, Date= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), DurationSec = 60, Phone = "", Region = new Country { From = "", To = ""}},
    ...
  };
  foreach (PhoneCall s in phoneCalls)
  {
    allCalls.Add(s as T);
  }

  var dataCalls = new DataCall[]
  {
    new DataCall{Id = 6, WebData = 5120, Phone = "", Region = new Country { From = "", To = ""}},
    ...
  };
  foreach (DataCall s in dataCalls)
  {
    allCalls.Add(s as T);
  }

  var smsCalls = new SmsCall[]
  {
    new SmsCall{Id = 6, SmsData = 512, Phone = "", Region = new Country { From = "", To = ""}},
    ...
  };
  foreach (SmsCall s in smsCalls)
  {
    allCalls.Add(s as T);
  }

  return allCalls;
```

Regarding the T that is a class which I have defined at the top of my Repository.cs class

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
```

Comment: Please show the declaration of `myGenericList`

Comment: What is T? Is it properly casting to the type T? Also can you please share myGenericList?

Comment: I guess the T is missing the were T:BaseClass constraint which defines the Id property. Perhaps this was an extension method which does not yet constrain the generic input type to anything yet.

Comment: It looks weird to have `s as T` in your `.Add(...);` calls. Either it's not needed because the classes extends from the base class, or they don't and then "null" is added instead. Why do you have the expression `s as T` in your code? And from which class does the classes `PhoneCall`, `DataCall` and `SmsCall` extends from.

Comment: The phone, data, and smscall all extend from the baseclass, only thing having in common is the id prop. I need to use the s as t since its a List<T>. if I omit the as T then I get error saying cant convert phonecall to T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried casting to the base class?

```
myGenericList
     .Cast<BaseClass>()
     .FirstOrDedault(i => i.Id === id)
```

Or alternatively

```
myGenericList.FirstOrDefault(i => (i as BaseClass).Id === id)
```

Comment: I think in this case a cast is a workaround instead of a solution

Comment: @GiladGreen maybe, but depends on how much control the OP has over the code. I took the question for what it is, they have a generic list which they want to treat as <X>. Could help guide others too should they come across this with a similar problem.

Comment: Hi the second option did it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you should do is define what `T` is and not cast the items to `T`. As the compiler has no way to know what `T` is it does not know it has the `Id` property. Use a generic constraint to do so:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Initialize<T where T : BaseClass>()
{
    var allCalls = new List<T>();
    allCalls.Add(new PhoneCall { /* Details */};
    return allCalls;
}
```

*After question update - move the constraint from being one of the function to being one of the class*

---

Also you can use the `FirstOrDefault` overload that gets a predicate:

```
var result = myGenericList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
```

Comment: I'm sorry about the T confusion. T is already defined at the top of the Repository.cs class. I just did paste the code for it. Here it goes: public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class

Comment: @Ovis - its not a problem :) I just think you should think about your design a bit - if this is a repository specifically for objects deriving from the base class then you can specify it in the generic constraint for the class. If you want to keep it "open" then I think it is a bit of a smell that the repository will create instances of the derived. If you really can't know the type from within the repository then think if the querying code should actually be in it.

Comment: Not convinced about this tbh, constraining what appears to be a pretty general func on a `Repository<T>` means anybody implementing this _must_ return data derived from `BaseClass` - which I assume wouldn't be the desired behaviour (based on `T: class`). This approach would only work if you derived from `Repository<T>` _then_ constrained `Initialize` e.g. `PhoneCallRepository`

Comment: @James - ya but to me it seems like specific class type logic that appears in a generic agnostic to any custom type should not sit in the generic class